# Groovy bundle for TextMate

Tags: ide, groovy, textmate

Where can I get the Groovy bundle for TextMate? I checked the [TextMate subversion repository](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/) but it's not there. The [Groovy site TextMate page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/TextMate) references TextMate's missing Groovy bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more searching it looks like the [Groovy bundle](http://github.com/textmate/groovy.tmbundle) moved to github. There's also a [Grails bundle](http://github.com/alkemist/Groovy-Grails.tmbundle) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The bundle has moved to github. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/TextMate for install instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find and install bundles on Textmate is using [GetBundles](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/). Place the tmbundle in the `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles`